# Sending Strings from NRF24L01 to app

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, nrf24l01+, wireless, ble

I want to send pushbutton status from the nrf24l01 module to the app named nrfConnect. I could only find libraries that allow me to send float values. How could I send String values to the app? Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

[nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp) is for Bluetooth LE devices, the nRF24L01+ is really not a Bluetooth Low Energy transceiver.

The best the nRF24L01+ can do is make a few Bluetooth LE advertisements but that's very finicky. Here's a long description how: https://dmitry.gr/index.php?r=05.Projects&proj=15&proj=11.%20Bluetooth%20LE%20fakery